# Can't connect to other VM port from internal network in Gcloud

Tags: gcloud, vpc

I have 2 VMs in the same "default" GCloud network: vm1 and vm2.

Inside vm1, I can:

> vm1:~$ curl localhost:5984
>
> {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"121d13a07f68","version":"1.6.0","vendor":{"version":"16.10","name":"Ubuntu"}}

Inside vm2, I can:

> vm2:~$ curl vm1-name

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.1 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to reach the 5984 port in vm1, I get:

> vm2:~$ curl vm1-name:5984
>
> curl: (7) Failed connect to vm1-name:5984; Connection refused

GCP adds a firewall rulle that let ingress all tcp:0-65535 traffic, so I don't understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

So... it wasn't a Gcloud problem after all.
I found the clue here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/79453/why-cant-i-access-my-couchdb-instance-externally-on-ubuntu-9-04-server

Just connect to vm1:5984/_utils/config.html (remember to login) and change **bind_address** to 0.0.0.0